# How can I force Lightroom to render previews for my collection?

Tags: lightroom, software, preview

When you import, you have the option (I just discovered 5 minutes ago) to have Lightroom render 1:1 previews. That makes it much easier to just quickly flip through a bunch of images, because it doesn't have to try to render them on the fly behind your back.

However, I have a bunch of images that are already in Lightroom which are not rendered at 1:1 scale. I'd like to have Lightroom render 1:1 previews for itself of those.

Is there a way to make that happen?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Select all the photos you want to render previews on (Ctrl-A or the like).
2. In the Menu system - Library -> Previews -> Render 1:1 Previews

Comment: Erm... d'oh! +1 :)