# Changing small delay before loading full resolution in Lightroom Classic

Tags: lightroom, performance

As I browse through images in Lightroom, it waits a bit (maybe a second or two) on every image before loading the full resolution version (when loading toast appears). I think this is for performance reasons preventing a full render as one is going over images without really needing to load them.

I was wondering if there is any way to adjust this delay?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force Lightroom to render previews for my collection?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13850/how-can-i-force-lightroom-to-render-previews-for-my-collection)

Answer (score 1):

This delay is internal setting and I think Adobe do not provide a way to change it. What you can do is to build smart preview and select Lightroom to use smart preview for editing. This will speed-up the process of display the fullres image on the screen. The change is not significant, but it is at least some change.